How to Require User ID for Liking a Post in a React and Express Application?
I'm developing a web application using React for the frontend and Express for the backend, and I want to implement a feature where users must be authenticated (and their user ID verified) to like a post.
I'm working on a web application using React for the frontend and Express for the backend, where users need to be authenticated to like a post. However, I'm facing challenges in implementing the functionality that requires a user ID to be associated with the action of liking a post. Here’s what I have so far:
1.Post Model: I have a Post model with a likes array to store the user IDs of those who liked the post.
2.API Endpoint: I created an endpoint in Express to handle the like action, but I'm unsure how to correctly verify the user ID and ensure that it is saved in the database.

current implementation
const  userId = req.user.id
const postId  = req.params.postId;

problems:
1.How do I verify that the user ID exists and is valid before allowing the like action?
2.What steps should I take to ensure that a user can only like a post once?
3.How do I handle scenarios where a user attempts to like a post multiple times
Any assistance or best practices on how to implement this feature correctly would be greatly appreciated!

"How do I verify that the user ID exists and is valid before allowing the like action?" - How would you generally check if that user exists at all?  Do you perhaps have a database with information about your users?  We don't know anything about your application.  "What steps should I take to ensure that a user can only like a post once?" - Store this information in a database, and check if this information already exists before trying to store it.  (Unique constraints on the data can help with this as well.)

"How do I handle scenarios where a user attempts to like a post multiple times" - If the user attempts to like a post which they already liked, either silently ignore it or display a message to the user.  It's entirely up to you how you want to handle this.  Overall... What you're asking seems to be very broad, potentially opinion-based, and not really answerable here.  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter any specific problems with that attempt, we can help with that.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
